# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I'm new to yii..i create one form in that i want to include the validations so i create one external file if i include that i got this error in chrome..if i select inspect elements it shows the html page but i use only php file how to recover it.how to include the external js in php on yii.i use one method tell me is that right or wrong.

```html
<?php 
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
  $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
  $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/logincheck.js');
  ?>
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $model LoginForm */
/* @var $form CActiveForm  */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - SimpleLogin';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
 'SimpleLogin',
);
?>

<h1>Login</h1>



<p>Please fill out the following form with your login credentials:</p>

<div class="form" onsubmit="check()">
<?php 
 $url=Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/newlogin');

echo CHtml::beginForm($url,'POST') ?>

 <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

 <div class="row",id="s">
  <?php echo CHtml::label('name',''); ?>
  <?php echo CHtml::textField('name','',array('onblur'=>"keyw()",'id'=>'s')); ?>
  
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <?php echo CHtml::label('password',''); ?>
  <?php echo CHtml::passwordField('password',''); ?>
  
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('role','',
     array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'),
              array('empty' => '(Select a gender)'));
?>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row buttons">
  <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit',array('name'=>'submit')); ?>
 </div>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($model->name)."-". CHtml::encode($model->password)."-".CHtml::encode($model->role);?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?> 

</div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: You have some syntax error in your **logincheck.js** not in yii.

Comment: first i check with a small function like,function check(){alert("hi);} this function also not work.

Comment: Can you post the body of  logincheck.js file?

Comment: i din't validate fully..i just try with this function check(){alert("hi);} but this also not work

Comment: If i give external link in view file it gives that syntax error..then where to give the link? but it works in internal script.

Comment: Probably something is wrong inside of js file.

Comment: i don't whats the problem know it shows another error that is,Uncaught ReferenceError: check() is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comments, you see `check() is not defined` error. This means **The external javascript file(logincheck.js) isn't included properly**. So, browser cant find `check()` function. Therefore, one possible problem is **Path to js file**. As a result `$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/logincheck.js')` is the first possible problem. Another possibility: there are somethings wrong inside `logincheck.js` file, for example syntax errors. You can inspect the browser console errors for more information.